# Setting <iframe>'s height to maximum document's height

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the following code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.externalsite.com/" style=""/>
```

Assume the total height of www.externalsite.com to be X pixels. X is unknown to me. How do I set height of the iframe to X pixels using CSS or other methods but no JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<iframe src="http://www.youraddress.com" frameborder="0"   style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: I request you to try to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12020988/1184247) too...

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.externalsite.com/" width="200" height="X"></iframe>
```

see here for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: ahh, sorry. Try 100% then. That should work.
    <iframe src="http://www.externalsite.com/" width="200" height="100%"></iframe>

Comment: `height="100%"` sets the height to browser's height, not document's height.

Comment: Do you want the iframe to scale with the page (ie. the content you're loading into it)? Have you tried "auto"?

Comment: `Do you want the iframe to scale with the page (ie. the content you're loading into it)?` Yes .....