# Not able to fix iframe height

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have the following sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.div_class
{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid blue;
left:50%;
margin-left:-375px;
margin-top:100px;
height:300px;
width:500px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.iframe_class
{
position:relative;
border:1px solid red;
height:100%;
margin-left:-218px;
margin-top:-110px;
}
</style>
<div class="div_class">
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" class="iframe_class" />
</div>
```

In the code above, a `div` encloses an `iframe` of which only a part (from position [x=218,y=110]) has to be displayed. As you can see, I have placed `height:100%` for `iframe` which means it takes the height of the `div`. This is where the problem starts. The iframe is cropped. ie. the iframe's right border and bottom border have moved with the repositioning.

**What I want:** Even after the repositioning of the iframe, I want the right border and the bottom border to coincide with the right border and bottom border of the div respectively. How do I do it?

**Note:**

1. http://www.w3schools.com/ is taken just as an example. In my actual code, the iframe source will be decided by a PHP script.
2. I cannot set the iframe height to **218+document_height_of_iframe_src** because as I said the src is dynamically decided by a backend script. So **document_height_of_iframe_src** will be unknown to me. Same is the case with **document_width_of_iframe_src**.
3. I have to accomplish all this without using JavaScript.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Uh.. a downvote was expected... My requirements are so complicated, This was the most I could explain... Please comment if you need me to clarify something....

Comment: +1 to cancel the -1 without explanation. Give everyone a chance to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Margin and border styles aren't included in an element width/height. So they have their own layout space. To fix it, add a bottom padding to the `iframe_class`'s container (the `div_class`) like this.

```
.div_class
{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid blue;
left:50%;
margin-left:-375px;
margin-top:100px;
height:300px;
width:500px;
overflow:hidden;
/*added to compensate iframe border (top+bottom)*/
padding-bottom:2px;
}
.iframe_class
{
position:relative;
border:1px solid red;
height:100%;
/*removed. messed the layout.
margin-left:-218px;
margin-top:-110px;
*/
}
```